# Div not moving even if there is enough space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make site when i click button profile shows. But i have problem. When i click button profile div is showing under body even if there is enough space.
Here is what it looks like:
[image on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzgYz.jpg)

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.calendar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all .5s;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.profile {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all .5s;
  float: right !important;
  display: none;
}

.close {
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button class="open">PROFILE</button>

<div class="calendar"></div>

<div class="profile">
  <button class="close">x</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Can you create a running demo for us on the various websites which do this?

Comment: @Fallenreaper no need for other websites, [it can be done right here, in the question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: here is my html: https://pastebin.com/7GG9WkQp

Comment: @Kamil this will be very difficult to give a definite answer to without the relevant HTML. However, you do seem to have given everything a height of 100%. And not everything is floated. Possibly you need to float the "calendar" element to the left, at a guess. But since we can't see which is which on your screenshot, it's hard to know what specifically causes the issue.

Comment: @KamilWaniczek please paste the (relevant parts of the) HTML here. There is no need for adding it on a different site. You can use the "edit" button to add information to your question. If you don't, it can be considered [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for not providing relevant info **within the question**. Thanks.

Comment: nah0131 already helped but thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
float: left
```

to your `.calendar`-class. This should fix your problem

Comment: np! if my answer helped please press the "accept answer" button right next to my answer :)

Comment: that was actually the "upvote" button. the tick is used to indicate that the question is answered ^^